# SQL Server - foreign key reference error

Tags: sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have two tables, `Table_1` with 4 columns (3 primary key) and `Table_2` with 2 column. When I try to create a foreign key constraint in `Table_2`, I am getting this error:

[image]

Here are the definitions of my tables:

**Table_1**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]
(
    [Field_1] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Field_2] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Field_3] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Field_4] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Field_1] ASC,
    [Field_2] ASC,
    [Field_3] ASC
)
```

**Table_2**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2]
(
    [Field_1] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Field_2] [tinyint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this? Thanks -

Comment: `Field_1` is not a primary key. You should either make it a primary key through the visual thingy or change the script for `Table_1` to `[Field_1] [tinyint] PRIMARY KEY`,

Comment: Hi Lieven, I'm sorry I forgot to add the primary keys on my sample table. Anyway, I have updated my table, now with primary keys defined. But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: For SQL Server to be able to create a foreign key, it has to be sure that there can only be **one** record returned for a given foreign key. As you have a primary key on multiple fields, there's no guarantee that `Field_1` will be unique. If you can't change your primary key, all you can do is add a unique index on `Table_1.Field_1`. If a unique index is also not possible, you can't create a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key of `Table_1` is *all three of* `Field_1`, `Field_2` and `Field_3`. In order to reference a key in another table, you have to reference *all* of the columns in that key - so you would need to add `Field_2` and `Field_3` to `Table_2`, and have all three columns included when you attempt to create the foreign key constraint.

Alternatively, if `Field_1`, by itself, is a key for `Table_1`, then declare it as such, either by redefining the primary key, or adding a `UNIQUE` constraint on just `Field_1` to `Table_1`. You would then be able to create the foreign key you're attempting to.

Comment: Adding a UNIQUE constraint solves the problem. Thanks Damien!